# Proof that $e^z=e^xe^{iy}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series

The proof goes like this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
e^z=e^{x+iy}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(x+iy)^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{x^k(iy)^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(iy)^m}{m!}=e^xe^{iy}.
\end{aligned}
$$

I want to ask how did they exactly separate indices in the step previous to last one.

Comment: This is the [Cauchy product](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cauchy_product) formula for multiplying two infinite series.

Comment: Note that this is the standard series proof for the identity $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$; it's unimportant that $a$ and $b$ are the real and imaginary parts of a complex number.

Comment: @Martin R I don't think this question should have been closed. It is asking for an explanation for, not a statement of, Cauchy's product formula - which doesn't appear in the duplicate.

Comment: @mcd: I have added another duplicate target where the Cauchy product is explained. All this has been asked and answered more than once.

Comment: The duplicates have helped me solve the doubt, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A diagram like this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e0exm3y4ga is often helpful in seeing what you are doing when changing the variables in a double sum: the values 0f $n$ are on the $x$-axis and the values of $m$ on the $y$-axis. The sum in line 2 corresponds to adding, for $n = 0$, the term corresponding to the one red dot $(0, 0)$; for $n = 1$, the terms corresponding to the two blue dots $(1, 0), (0, 1)$; for $n = 2$, the terms corresponding to the three blue dots $(2, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2)$ and so on. These are the same terms, counted in a different order, in the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n(iy)^m}{n!m!},$$ which can now be separated as in line 3.